# Database connection over ssh tunnel

Tags: mysql, ssh

If client is connected to sql server via ssh what protocol is used to send sql query and  receive data from sql table?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the connection itself, that would be TCP/IP. Correct me if I am wrong.